# In Ubuntu OS, my "arrow keys" are not arrow keys

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

Instead, they give A, B, C, D

I am using vi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*vi* doesn't have support for arrow keys.  However, chances are you're actually using *vim*, which *vi* is often symlinked to for compatibility (I'm not certain what Ubuntu does, so I'm just guessing).  Although *vim* supports the arrow keys, they tend to be disabled when run as *vi*.

If you are using *vim*, you can try typing the following command:

```
:set nocompatible
```

and see if that fixes the problem.  This can also be loaded into your *~/.vimrc* configuration file to load automatically every time you start the program.

Alternatively, you can run *vim* instead of *vi*.

Comment: Running `vim` in [mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) (Cygwin) didn't solve the problem for me - but `:set nocompatible` did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`vi` never did and never will support arrow keys. The correct movement keys in `vi` are <kbd>h</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd>. I suggest you [learn](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_editor/Basic_tasks) to use `vi` this way, or switch to another text editor. `nano` is popular and straightforward for small tasks. `vim` is popular for people who like `vi` but want extra features like syntax coloring, and yes, arrow key support.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an old version of vi. In older versions, you would navigate using the H, J, K, and L keys. To get the latest vi, do

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

If you want the GUI too, use

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Comment: That's `vim`, not `vi`.